# TextBox as PasswordBox

Tags: c#, textbox, passwords, windows-phone-8

Just have this quick question.
Can I some how make a TextBox to a PasswordBox, or just use "UseSystemPasswordChar".

This is for windows phone.

Now have an icon that I can tap and want to display password and when keyup it hides it again. But since this is for WP it may not bet that easy.

Can't use a PasswordBox beacause that is not allowed on other parts of my application.

**UPDATE**
The textbox I am using looks like this:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="password" BorderBrush="#BF000000" SelectionForeground="White" BorderThickness="2" SelectionBackground="#FF282A6C" Text="{Binding Path=PasswordSetting, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource setting}}" TextChanged="sign_TextChanged_1" Foreground="Black" Background="White"/>
```

In codebehide if i had a password box i cant have **passwordbox.Text.Lenght**

**UPDATE 2**

I solved it, this was a dumb question from the beggning.

Comment: Have added update with the TextBox i am using and wish that i chould get the passwordbox work the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TextBox control by settings its `TextMode` attribute to `Password`.  This should be handled as an ordinary HTML Input that masks for passwords...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

Comment: Yes but this is for Windows Phone.